# Problem 16 chapter 5 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f$ is twice-differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, $f''$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$, and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. Prove that $f'(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

We'll use the following theorem (without proof).

**Theorem (Landau):** Suppose $a\in \mathbb{R}^1$, $f$ is twice-differentiable real function on $(a,\infty)$, and $M_0, M_1, M_2$ are the least upper bounds of $|f(x)|, |f'(x)|, |f''(x)|$, respectively, on $(a,\infty)$. Prove that $$M_1^2\leqslant 4M_0M_2.$$

**Proof:** Since $|f''(x)|\leqslant K$ on $(0,\infty)$ and let $a\in (0,\infty)$ and by Landau's theorem $$\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)} |f'(x)|\leqslant 2 \sqrt{\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)} |f(x)|\cdot\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)} |f''(x)|}\leqslant 2 \sqrt{K\cdot \sup\limits_{(a,\infty)} |f(x)|}=$$ 
$$=L\sqrt{\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)}|f(x)|}$$ where $L=2\sqrt{K}$. Let $M_0^a=\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)}|f(x)|$ and $M_1^a=\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)}|f'(x)|$ and we have $M_1^a\leqslant LM_0^a$. But $M_0^a\to 0$ as $a\to\infty$  since $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. So $M_1^a=\sup\limits_{(a,\infty)}|f'(x)|\to 0$ as $a\to \infty$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f'(x)|\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ $\Rightarrow$ $f'(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

Suppose $|f'(x)|\nrightarrow 0$ as $x\to \infty$. It means that $\exists {x_n}$ such that $x_n\to \infty$ but $|f'(x_n)|>\varepsilon_0$ for some $\varepsilon_0>0$. Taking $a_n:=\dfrac{x_n+x_{n+1}}{2}$ $(x_n<a_n<x_{n+1})$ we see that $a_n\to \infty$ and $\sup\limits_{(a_n,+\infty)}|f'(x)|>\varepsilon_0$ and $M_1^{a_n}\nrightarrow 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Contradiction.

Sorry if topic repeated but I solve this problem myself and it would be very great if somebody would check my solution please.

Comment: Seems to me you are working too hard.  Most of us would say that the problem follows immediately from the inequality that you established in lines 2 and 3 of your proof.   Wouldn't we?  [The spirit of the problem though would require a direct proof rather than an appeal to a general version.]

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, You are right! But I can solve this only by above method? Can you look at this and check it please?

Comment: After the inequality is established do this. Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $A$ large enough that $|f(x)|<\epsilon^2/L^2$ for all $x>A$.  Then, by the inequality, $|f'(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x>A$.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, Nice idea! But we get $\sup \limits_{(a,\infty)}|f'(x)|<\varepsilon$ for $x>A$. Hence $|f'(x)|<\varepsilon$ for $x>\max\{a,A\}=A$. It means that $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0$. Am I right?